# Svelte dynamic multiple component array

Tags: typescript, svelte

EDIT: REPL for answer https://svelte.dev/repl/eb7616fd162a4829b14a778c3d1627e4?version=3.48.0

What I'm talking would render this:

First we have a button:

```
<button on:click={add}> Add </button>
<div id="columnflexbox">
```

When I click it, this should happen:

```
<button on:click={add}> Add </button>
<!-- This exists in DOM-->
<div id="columnflexbox">

<!-- This div and components get rendered, the Div does not exist in DOM -->
<div class="row" style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
comp1 (instance1) 
comp2 (instance1)
</div>
```

When I click it again, another row gets added (with new instances):
 Add

```
<div id="columnflexbox">


<div class="row" style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
comp1 (instance1) 
comp2 (instance1)
</div>
<!-- Second div is generated, it does not exist in DOM, new instances of components -->
<div class="row" style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
comp1 (instance2)
comp2 (instance2)
</div>


</div>
```

There is an interface:

```
export interface complexObject {
    comp1 : ComplexObj1
    comp2: ComplexObj2
}

let row: complexObject[] = []
```

Add function:

```
function add(){        
    let newObj:complexObject = {
        comp1: new Comp1({target: div}), // I have to add a target here, or I get compile error, but how since the element doesn't exist?
        comp2: new Comp2({target: div})
    }

    row.push(newObj);
}
```

I would use this way of doing it, but I can't since I'm getting compile error without adding target:

```
{#each row as rowitem }

    <div class="row">
        {rowitem.comp1}
        {rowitem.comp2}
    </div>
    
{/each}
```

Edit: It turns out that the styling gets applied correctly when I add the target as the html specified in the render as so:

Add function:

```
function add(){    
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute('class',"row")


    let newObj:complexObject = {
        comp1: new Comp1({target: div}),
        comp2: new Comp2({target: div})
    }

    row.push(newObj);
}


{#each row as rowitem }
<div class="row">
        {rowitem.comp1}
        {rowitem.comp2}
</div>    
        

{/each}
```

Now the problem is that the components do not get rendered, what I get instead is

```
[object Object]     [object Object]
```

When I try to render as such:

```
  <svelte:component this={rowitem.comp1}>

    </svelte:component>
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: l is not a constructor
```

If I try to modify Add function and remove `new` keyword I get this:

```
Type 'typeof comp1__SvelteComponent_' is missing the following properties from type 'comp1__SvelteComponent_': $$prop_def, $$events_def, $$slot_def, $on, and 5 more.ts(2740)
```

Turns out that this is a problem with specifying the interface, it should be specified like so:

```
export interface complexObject {
    comp1 : typeof ComplexObj1
    comp2: typeof ComplexObj2
}
```

Comment: *" what I get instead is [object Object]"* This is because with `comp1: new Comp1({target: div})` comp1 holds a reference to the component which can't be used to create it in the html part. Have a look at [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/dfd5682bfdae4e5ab8d549a5dffbcf48?version=3.48.0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this, one would usually use [`svelte:component`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-component) which uses the constructor of the component as input and any props one may want to pass along. e.g.

```html
<script>
    import Comp from './Comp.svelte';
    
    let components = [
        [Comp, { content: 'Initial' }],
        [Comp, { content: 'Initial 2' }],
    ];
    function add(component, props) {
        components = [...components, [component, props]];
    }
</script>

<button type=button on:click={() => add(Comp, { content: 'Added' })}>
    Add
</button>

{#each components as [component, props]}
    <svelte:component this={component} {...props}>
        (Slotted content)
    </svelte:component>
{/each}
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/ffd96f167e594db58143ee5fd45148f0?version=3.48.0)

---

Example with types:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import type { SvelteComponent, SvelteComponentTyped } from 'svelte';
    import Comp from './Comp.svelte';
    import Comp2 from './Comp2.svelte';
    
    let components: [typeof SvelteComponent, Record<string, any>][] = [
        [Comp, { content: 'Initial' }],
        [Comp2, { color: 'blue' }],
    ];
    function add<T extends typeof SvelteComponentTyped<P, any, any>, P>(
        component: T,
        props: P
    ) {
        components = [...components, [component, props]];
    }
</script>
```

`add` enforces the consistency between the component and its props, the array cannot, at least when using tuples. If each item were a class, the class could enforce its internal type consistency.

Comment: Thank you for pushing me in the right direction, but this answer is in JS and while I understand most of it, I'm trying to find a solution specific to typescript.

Comment: Adding types would not make this any easier to understand, if anything, it would be more complicated. If you want to type this with a high level of accuracy you need to employ generics and use inferred generic typing for the component properties. Not sure if that would really be worth the trouble.

Comment: You might be correct, I do quite often get stuck with this kind of stuff because of using typescript, and every time think it's not worth the trouble. But I do like to create custom types between the server and client as it makes easier to keep track of things.

Comment: @sander: Added an example with some typing...

Answer (score 1):

If you need a reference to a DOM element, you can either query it inside `onMount` or set a reference to a variable via `bind:this` (then as well defined/accessible inside onMount) [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f4a7afed2f61481c8a3f84795ab2433f?version=3.48.0)

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'
    import Comp from './Comp.svelte'
    let container
    
    onMount(() => {
        const containerRef = document.getElementById('container')
        console.log(containerRef, container)
        const c = new Comp({target: container})
    })
</script>

<div id="container" bind:this={container} />
```

(You query `getElementByID` but your outer element has `class="columnflexbox"` and do you iterate `newObjs` or `row`? Because first is an object and can't be directly iterated I think...)

Comment: Sorry, those were typos from typing the question. Edited my question.

Comment: @sander No problem. Does it help you with your case? *"The problem is that the div class "row" doesn't exist in dom so it can't be set as the target in the initialization of the component."*

Comment: @sander *" In vanilla JS I would just create the object in the dom ..."* If the element doesn't exist yet, you can also just create it in Svelte like with in js ~ see the updated REPL

Comment: Updated the answer to format the question better.

Comment: @sander I see, so I think H.B.'s answer covers this. Use `<svelte:component>` instead of `new Comp()` https://svelte.dev/repl/eb7616fd162a4829b14a778c3d1627e4?version=3.48.0